# Difference of intersections of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Could you check the formulas please? I can use formulas (1) and (2) as already proven and the task is to get the formula for difference of intersections. I do it in two ways and the results are different:
[image]

I'm a little bit confused with the following fact:

[image]

In general there is no equality between these two sets - and in my case there IS equality:
[image]

Is it OK or there are some mistakes? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In YOUR case it is right, since

$$\bigcup_k\bigcap_i(A_i \setminus B_k) = \bigcup_k(\bigcap_i(A_i \cap {\overline B_k})) = \bigcup_k((\bigcap_iA_i) \cap {\overline B_k})) = \bigcap_i A_i \cap (\bigcup_k{\overline B_k})=$$
$$\bigcap_i (A_i \cap (\bigcup_k{\overline B_k})) = \bigcap_i(\bigcup_k (A_i \cap {\overline B_k}))=  \bigcap_i(\bigcup_k (A_i \setminus B_k)).
$$